# Fantasy magic Manga where Mc got a spell placed on him that siphons off his power

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for the manga where the MC was a really strong wizard who was protecting the hero's party but then someone from the party put a curse on him which siphoned his powers and fed them to the hero.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: I read this about 2 weeks ago @DavidW

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 2):

I got you. I am pretty sure you are thinking of Boukensha License o Hakudatsu Sareta Ossan Dakedo, Manamusume ga Dekita no de Nonbiri Jinsei / I'm a Middle-Aged Man Who Got My Adventurer License Revoked, but I Can Enjoy Life Because I Have a Lovely Daughter. [anilist](https://anilist.co/manga/108801/Boukensha-License-wo-Hakudatsu-Sareta-Ossan-Dakedo-Manamusume-ga-Dekita-no-de-Nonbiri-Jinsei-wo-Ouka-Suru):

> Douglas, once known as a legendary enhancement spellcaster, is now little more than your average, weak old man. On top of that, he was kicked out of the hero party, and eventually had his adventurer's license revoked... And that's how he ended up a vagabond, wandering aimlessly. After an encounter with Rabi, a cursed little girl, a new adventure begins...

Comment: Does he have the spell siphoning off his power?

Comment: Yup, someone from the party hexed him so that, over time, his power would be drained and siphoned to the hero. He became weaker as the hero became more powerful. The manga starts with him leaving the city because he was kicked out of the hero party and lost his adventurer card after failing too many quests.

Comment: :) That would a good thing to [edit] into the answer.